# Python собрать запрос в байтах

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, mtproto

Подскажите как собрать байты последовательно как в примере, на Python
https://tlgrm.ru/docs/mtproto/samples-auth_key#key-gen

Там написано Запрос (p,q)-авторизации параметры и после сбора конечный запрос в байтах:

```
Параметр        Сдвиг, длина в байтах   Значение                            Описание
auth_key_id     0, 8                    0                                   Поскольку сообщение незашифрованное
message_id      8, 8                    51e57ac42770964a                    Точный unixtime * 2^32
message_length  16, 4                   20                                  Длина тела сообщения
%(req_pq)       20, 4                   60469778                            Номер конструктора req_pq из TL-схемы
nonce           24, 16                  3E0549828CCA27E966B301A48FECE2FC    Случайное число

0000 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4A 96 70 27 C4 7A E5 51
0010 | 14 00 00 00 78 97 46 60 3E 05 49 82 8C CA 27 E9
0020 | 66 B3 01 A4 8F EC E2 FC
```

Я хочу понять как собирать на Python в переменную эту последовательность байтов. Допустим выделил bytes(40) байт нулями. Дальше как ее заполнить чтоб сдвиги были верные? В общем как мне собрать эту конструкцию запроса. Есть ли примеры именно на Python или какую литературу почитать?

И еще как получить этот unixtime * 2^32 в Python?

Comment: Скопируйте пример и более подробное описание в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Эникейщик, fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, сработает?

Накидал пример через [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
import datetime
import random
import struct

auth_key_id = 0

d = datetime.datetime.now()
unix_time = int(d.timestamp())
message_id = unix_time * (2 ** 32)

message_length = 20

req_pq = b'\x60\x46\x97\x78'  # Это же значение b'`F\x97x'
# OR:
# req_pq = bytes.fromhex('60 46 97 78')
nonce = random.getrandbits(8 * 8), random.getrandbits(8 * 8)

msg = struct.pack('<QQI4BQQ', auth_key_id, message_id, message_length, *req_pq[::-1], *nonce)
print(len(msg), msg)
# 40 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00t<\xc0\\\x14\x00\x00\x00x\x97F`W9\xcfQ;\x16\xee\xd3\xd5_at\xd3S\xab\xa9'

print(msg.hex())
# 000000000000000000000000743cc05c14000000789746605739cf513b16eed3d55f6174d353aba9
```

---

**PS.**

```
< - задает порядок байтов как little-endian
Q - unsigned long long (8 байтов)
I - unsigned int (4 байта)
B - unsigned char (1 байт)
4B - тоже самое что BBBB
```

Comment: @АртемШахматист, отпишитесь, пожалуйста, правильно ли собирается массив байт? (у меня нет возможности самому это проверить)

Comment: почти правильно, только при создании message_id всегда получается что то около 00 00 00 00 50 12 c0 5c с 4 нулями, а в примере нет нулей 4A 96 70 27 C4 7A E5 51, незнаю влияет ли это правильно или нет. Потом второе в примере req_pq = 60469778 - это уже байты и записываются в такой последовательности 78 97 46 60. Но в общем направление думаю верное. Пока сам пробую исправить. И было бы не плохо если вы чего поправите.

Comment: @АртемШахматист, `00 00 00 00 50 12 c0 5c` это 6683361981824499712 -> 6683361981824499712 / (2**32) = 1556091472 (ваш unix time). А то, что в примере тоже правильно, но дата другая (кст 4A 96 70 27 C4 7A E5 51 это 5901257869632771658, что явно меньше вашей текущей даты)

Comment: @АртемШахматист, обновил ответ. для req_pq теперь записывается в обратном порядке